# Return values in an if operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have started javascript, and I know how if statements work. One thing that I am wondering about is the return values for some things. For example lets say we have

```
if (evt.keyCode) {
// do stuff
}
```

Does evt.keyCode have a return value? Because I know that if the item in the if statement is true, it will execute the code in the statement without the need for a == operator. For example,

```
let myVar = true;
if (myVar) {
// do something
}
```

Besides evt.keyCode I have seen document.removeEventListener and document.addEventListener. Can someone explain to me how this works?
Sorry if I haven't explained things clearly.

Comment: JavaScript is a C-like language. One of its similarities is how it handles logical values. Aside from the fact that JS has true/false, anything that is zero or can be converted to zero is false, anything else is true. Null and undefined are such zero-like things. `evt.keyCode` is present only when it is a keyboard event, otherwise it will be undefined. The example you have posted is just testing if this field of the `evt` object is defined or not, thus the block of the `if` statement is executed only if the handler was called with a keyboard event.

Comment: @ZorgoZ `undefined` and `NaN` aren't really convertible to zero. `null` and an empty string aren't *always* convertible to zero, either. Falsy values don't just mean "relates to zero".

Comment: @VLAZ read my comment carefully. I wrote "zero-like", not convertible to zero. Too many details do not mean a better understanding for OP at such level.

Comment: @ZorgoZ "*anything that is zero or can be converted to zero is false*"

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, that is an other statement. Is it untrue? Is there anything that is zero or convertible to zero that is treated as `true` in JS? I just said that there are other things too that are treated as false -  I said that they are _zero-like_ and not that they are convertible to zero. That does mean that your statements is also valid. So why are you arguing?

Comment: @ZorgoZ The statement "anything that is zero or can be converted to zero is false, anything else is true" implies that all falsy values are convertible to zero. Which is not the case. And yes, there are definitely things that are convertible to zero but *aren't* falsy `+[]` will convert the array to a number by getting its length - the length is zero (empty array), so `+[] === 0`, yet `if ([]) console.log("this will execute")`. Anything that have `valueOf` or `@@toPrimitive` set so that it produces zero on conversion will still be *truthy*. Falsymess is simply not judged in relation to zero.